# Calculating http overhead and headers

Tags: android, http, tcp

I was wondering if someone could provide me with help on calculating overhead when requesting data via AndroidHttpClient get/post requests.

Why I ask?
The recently developed app shows different traffic usage when calculating payload and internet provider stats.
Simply put, all data sent/received by my app is 6MB, but provider shows 16. That's > 200%.

Since all communication is done via one function, I can track all payload size, and that additional size must be overhead. But is it really that big, or I'm missing something?
Here is a function:

```
public byte[] get(final String url, int timeout) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = new URI(url);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            lastError = ERROR_URL;
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        out += uri.toString().length();

        final HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeout);
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeout);
        get.setParams(httpParameters);

        HttpResponse responce;
        final long st = System.currentTimeMillis();
        responce = client.execute(get, localContext);
        ping = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() - st);

        InputStream is = responce.getEntity().getContent();

        byte[] data = inputStreamToByteArray(is);
        responce.getEntity().consumeContent();
        in += data.length;
        lastError = ERROR_SUCCESS;

        return data;

    }
```

IPOverhead = 26 bytes;
TCPOverhead = 20 bytes;

And now HTTP comes in, but how to measure it's overhead?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP's overhead is just made of the status line + the headers.
Using Android's Apache `HttpResponse` allows one to get the status line and headers (using [`getStatusLine`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html#getStatusLine%28%29) and [`getAllHeaders()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpMessage.html#getAllHeaders%28%29), but in a parsed way, not in raw text. Status line and headers are all uniformly defined (by [RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) §6.1 and §4.2 respectively), but they may have an arbitrary number of (non-parsed) whitespace, so we can only *roughly* determine overhead here.

Unless using another API or raw Android [Sockets](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) (which would require to implement your own HTTP handling), you're only half there.